# I don't know how this 16Bit value change to decimal value

Tags: floating-point, byte, decimal, 16-bit, modbus-tcp

[image: protocol]

How 0x3333 0x41DF could be 27.9 value?

I use hexadecimal to decimal value but it was 1B.E6666666666666666666.

Comment: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: https://www-sop.inria.fr/sinus/Softs/Vigie/HHDB/ieee.html

Comment: There's no obvious standard for "16 bits decimal floating-point" numbers. I don't blame you for the confusion, whoever wrote this does not understand the concept. "real" is redundant with "floating" here.

Comment: @MSalters : it is actually a 32-bit single precision value, I think the OP is confused.

Comment: @MSalters It is 32-bit IEEE-754. It is simply split to 2 16-bit integer registers, because Modbus protocol is ancient.

Comment: Example: 0x41df3333 as a single precision 32-bit ieee-754 number is 27.9

Comment: Oh help. This is middle-endian? `0x999A41E9` becomes `0x9A99E941` = 29.2? I can see why that would be confusing.

Comment: @MSalters The two 16-bit word values combine to form: 0x41e9999a which is 29.2

Answer (score 1):

0x3333 0x41DF combined = 0x41DF3333.  As a 32 bit IEEE float, this is evaluated as follows:

Convert to binary:

```
0x41DF3333 = 
4    1    D    F    3    3    3    3 = 
0100 0001 1101 1111 0011 0011 0011 0011 = 
01000001110111110011001100110011
```

Evaluate as a 32 bit IEEE float:

```
01000001110111110011001100110011 =


Sign (s)  Exponent (e)               Significand (S)
                                         11111111112222
                                12345678901234567890123
----      --------------------  -----------------------
0         10000011=1+2+128=131  10111110011001100110011

     s         e        assumed 1   S1          S2          S3                 S21           S22           S23   
(-1)^0 x 2^(131-127) x (1         + 1 x 1/2^1 + 0 x 1/2^2 + 1 x 1/2^3  + ... + 0 x 1/2^21  + 1 x 1/2^22  + 1 x 1/2^23)           =
1      x 2^( 4     ) x (1 x 1/2^0 + 1 x 1/2^1 + 0 x 1/2^2 + 1 x 1/2^3  + ... + 0 x 1/2^21  + 1 x 1/2^22  + 1 x 1/2^23)           = 
                       (1 x 2^4   + 1 x 2^3   + 0 x 2^2   + 1 x 2^1    + ... + 0 x 1/2^17  + 1 x 1/2^18  + 1 x 1/2^19)           = 
                       (1 x 2^23  + 1 x 2^22  + 0 x 2^21  + 1 x 2^20   + ... + 0 x 1/2^2   + 1 x 1/2^1   + 1 x 1/2^0 ) / 2^19    = 
                       (1           1           0           1                  0             1             1)          / 524288  =
                       (110111110011001100110011                                                            )          / 524288  =
                       (1101 1111 0011 0011 0011 0011                                                       )          / 524288  =
                       (14299955                                                                            )          / 524288  =
27.899999618530273
```

The last calculation used a calculator.
Noting that tha last non-zero digit after the decimal point, 3, is not 5, we know this is not the exact value.
The following code gets the exact float value:

```
Mac_3.2.57$cat floatGet.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    union Data {
        int i;
        float f;
    }data;

    data.i = 0x41DF3333; 

    printf("%100.100f\n", data.f);

    return 0;
}
Mac_3.2.57$cc floatGet.c
Mac_3.2.57$./a.out 
27.8999996185302734375000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Mac_3.2.57$
```